# How can I view other people's calendar in Microsoft Outlook web interface?

Tags: outlook-on-the-web, outlook.com-calendar

How can I view other people's calendar in Microsoft Outlook web interface when scheduling a meeting?

On Outlook for Microsoft Windows, I can view other people's calendars when creating a new meeting:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click on this icon when creating a new meeting:

[image]

[image]

It'll allow you to view other people's calendar in Microsoft Outlook web interface when scheduling a meeting:

[image]